# Placeholder for DataFrame in pd.query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use `pd.query` and `pd.eval` a lot. However, sometimes I find myself in situations where I would like to filter an unnamed DataFrame with `pd.query` and it would be very handy if I could use a name for the DataFrame in the query expression. For sake of an example, consider this DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4),
        columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['x', 'y']]))
>>> df
    A       B    
    x   y   x   y
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
```

Now, to get the `y` columns with values above 15 it would feel natural for me to try something like

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'y')].query('(PLACEHOLDER > 15).any(1)')
```

My question is: Is there such a placeholder to refer to the DataFrame, on which `query` has been called, for use in the expression? This would save me a lot of typing in many situations.

Comment: `loc` accepts a function `df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'y')].loc[lambda current_df: ...]` you're looking for a `query` equivalent?

Comment: oh, that's handy! 
Yes, sort of... Essentially I would like to have a handle for the current DataFrame available in the `query` / `eval` expression.